# UIWebView sizeThatFits only works in delegate method

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

So I use a UIWebView like a UILabel with a UITextBox that changes its text via

```
@IBAction func textChanged(_ sender: Any){}
```

I size the UIWebView to the size of its content with a fixed width and a flexible height using

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label = WebLabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 1))
    label.delegate = self
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    self.view.addSubview(label)
}
```

Where WebLabel is a class derived from UIWebView which implements following method :

```
func set(query: String)
{
    let htmlString = makeHTMLString(input: (query))
    self.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
    self.sizeToFit()
}
```

So with this textChanged I get my desired result :

```
 @IBAction func textChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    label.set(query: (sender as! UITextField).text!)
    label.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x, y: label.frame.origin.y, width: label.frame.width, height: 1)

    let size = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)

    label.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x, y: label.frame.origin.y, width: label.frame.width, height: size.height)
}
```

But I also want to set a initial html text. I do this using:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    label.set(query: "Hello World !")
    label.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x, y: label.frame.origin.y, width: label.frame.width, height: 1)

    let size = label.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)

    label.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x, y: label.frame.origin.y, width: label.frame.width, height: size.height)
}
```

But that doesn't work. So the code seems to only work when triggered by user in the delegate method. How do I solve this problem ? Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Sometimes the View of your ViewController is not done with layouting in the viewDidAppear method. Maybe u can try to find a moment after viewDidApear ? A very bad, ugly solution... try to run a method initLabel (performeWithDelay) with a delay 1 sec .... from your viewDidAppear method...

Comment: I thought about that "not finished yet" approach but wanted a second opinion. I will research about that performWithDelay and get back to you. Thanks a lot =)

Comment: That worked fine =) Thanks a lot again =)